# Represent "while t < time limit" in a UML Activity diagram

Tags: uml

I am drawing a diagram that represents the following:

- A user clicks a button on the user interface to edit a post
- The post status is set to "locked"
- The user has a time limit to edit the post
- If the time limit is exceeded then the user cannot save his/her edit
- Else if the time limit is not exceeded then the user can save his/her edit
- The post status is set to "unlocked"

The purpose of this example is to establish how to represent "while time limit is not exceeded" in a UML Activity diagram

I have tried to create a UML Activity diagram but it does not seem right.

Could you please suggest how to correctly draw it? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You might use the `interrupting edge` - https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html#interrupting-edge to interrupt the editing when the timer exceeds

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, xmojmr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @xmojmr commented you would use

> **15.7.19 InterruptibleActivityRegion [Class]**
>
> 15.7.19.1 Description
>
> An InterruptibleActivityRegion is an ActivityGroup that supports the termination of tokens flowing in the portions of an activity within it.

[image]

The `TimerOverrun` event can send an exception while `Action1` (or any other inside the dashed region) is active which is handled by `TimerEvent`.